# Is K7803-500R3 DC-DC converter "enough" for my circuit?

Tags: pcb-design, dc-dc-converter

I have recently made a relay board powered by 12V and using a DC-DC conveter to step down to 3.3V . My question is as the title says, is the K7803-500R3 converter good enough for my board or should I look into buck converters?

Schematic:
[image]
PCB Layout:
[image]

Comment: What's your definition for "good enough"? How much current you need and how much it can provide current? Also one aspect makes no sense because the regulator you think about using already is a buck regulator.

Comment: @Justme Sorry for not being clear, I meant if it's safe and won't cause any problems in the future because I didn't find much about it and if it's being used commonly. Well, I'm a little confused in that and was hoping for some clarification here because I have read multiple values for ESP-12f's current consumption - from 70mA, 170mA, 500mA and even 800mA. So I'm not totally sure about this. But the others components that I'm powering from 3.3V are each under 5mA if I'm right, and there is 4 of them - 1xPCF8575 and 3x74HC14. So maybe I should go for 1A minumum to be sure?

Answer (score 0):

We can't really guarantee yes or no if the regulator "is safe" and "won't cause any problems in the future", we cannot know that for 100% certainty. Especially if you don't apply the external components as per datasheet suggestions.

However, you have chosen a regulator rated at 500mA.

If you know that your ESP module can take 800mA, 500mA is not enough.

Comment: Well I'm new in this and that's why I'm asking here for help to learn something, so if I did something wrong that you know about then I will appreciate your advice how I can do it better. I see 2 capacitors in the datasheet. One on input side and one on output side, both 10uF. Or am I'm missing something? And as I said, I don't know the exact current consumption of the ESP and the 800mA wasn't the answer, but just one of many values I found.

Comment: @k0cka The output capacitor is 22uF. And if you want better EMC compliance, there is an example for that too.